# Getting Error for not Initializing Instance of class in my SharedPrefManager class.Not able to solve

Tags: android, mysql, database, kotlin, android-volley

> SharedPrefManager.kt

```
class SharedPrefManager private constructor(context: Context) {

lateinit  var mCtx: Context


fun isLoggedIn(): Boolean {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

fun username(): String {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null)
}

fun userEmail(): String {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, null)
}

init {
    mCtx = context
}

fun userLogin(id: Int, username: String, email: String): Boolean {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID, id)
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, email)
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username)
    editor.apply()
    return true
}

fun logout(): Boolean {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.clear()
    editor.apply()
    return true
}

companion object {
    lateinit var mInstance: SharedPrefManager
    private val SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mysharedpref12"
    private val KEY_USERNAME = "username"
    private val KEY_USER_EMAIL = "useremail"
    private val KEY_USER_ID = "userid"
    @Synchronized
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SharedPrefManager {
        if (mInstance == null) {
         line:59----->   mInstance = SharedPrefManager(context)
        }
        return mInstance
    }
}
```

}

> This is the error which i am getting

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.shikh.kotlinmysql, PID: 6600
                  kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: **lateinit property mInstance has not been initialized**
                      at ***com.example.shikh.kotlinmysql.SharedPrefManager$Companion.getMInstance(SharedPrefManager.kt:59)***
                      at ***com.example.shikh.kotlinmysql.SharedPrefManager$Companion.getInstance(SharedPrefManager.kt:66)***
                      at ***com.example.shikh.kotlinmysql.Login$userLogin$stringRequest$2.onResponse(Login.kt:34)***
                      at ***com.example.shikh.kotlinmysql.Login$userLogin$stringRequest$2.onResponse(Login.kt:29)***

> Login.kt

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity() , View.OnClickListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener(this)
}

private fun userLogin() {
    val username = editTextUser.text.toString().trim()
    val password = editTextPass.text.toString().trim()

   line:29----> val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_LOGIN,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

   line:34----> SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext).userLogin(
                                obj.getInt("id"),
                                obj.getString("username"),
                                obj.getString("email")
                        )

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "User log in Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            object : Response.ErrorListener {
                override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params.put("username", username)
            params.put("password", password)
            return params
        }

    }
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if (v==buttonLogIn){
        userLogin()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Kotlin 1.2 you should check if mInstance is initialised like this:

```
if (!::mInstance.isInitialized) {
  mInstance = SharedPrefManager(context)
}
```

Comment: got no error but when i click on login button it does'nt give any response